# Reformat single cell content into multiple with headers

Tags: excel, csv, formatting

I have an order export from an online shop that export variables as a single cell in an .csv file.

```
tier: Elite | division: Male/Male Team | captain shirt size: Large | teammate shirt size: XLarge | Team Name: Terrible 2's | Participant/Volunteer Waiver &amp; Liability Release   Captain's Full Name: Craig Carroll | Participant/Volunteer Waiver &amp; Liability Release   Teammate's Full Name: Ashley Carroll | Waiver &amp; Release of All Claims &amp; Assumption of Risk   Captain's Intials: cc | Waiver &amp; Release of All Claims &amp; Assumption of Risk   Teammate's Initials: ac | Age Requirement: Yes
```

This is what it exports into one cell.  Is there a way to make the word preceding the : become a header, as in A1, and the text preceding the | become the value in A2?  I have played around with the text to columns feature but it creates cells formatted as `tier:Elite` and so on.  Any suggestions for a solution for 400 orders or line items?

original
[image: original]

expectation 
[image: ![expectation]

and so on

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the following steps:

- Use text to columns as you mentioned with `|` as the delimiter
- Then transpose the data down (highlight the row, copy, select a cell to paste to then edit special transpose)
- With the transposed data use text to columns again, this time with `:` as the delimiter

The data would end up in the format:

```
tier                 Elite 
division             Male/Male Team 
captain shirt size   Large 
teammate shirt size  XLarge 
Team Name            Terrible 2's
...
```

(Only showed the first five rows as there is a lot of text in the other rows)

Comment: This is a great and simple solution for a single order. However, do you think this will work if I had 400 different orders?

Comment: @CraigCarroll for that I would recommend using vba, to separate and clean so it is in nice columnar data form.  But that is not what you asked, you asked for one cell and Sam Gave you an answer for that.

Comment: Thanks, I mistyped what I was looking for B1 was to be A2.

Comment: I've updated the question. I apologize for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

This macro assumes that the original data is in column **A** of *Sheet1*.  The reorganized data will be placed in *Sheet2*:

```
Sub ReOrganize()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, K As Long
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    K = 1

    For i = 1 To N
        ary = Split(Cells(i, "A").Value, "|")
        For Each a In ary
            bry = Split(a, ":")
            With Sheets("Sheet2")
                .Cells(K, 1).Value = bry(0)
                .Cells(K, 2).Value = bry(1)
                K = K + 1
            End With
        Next a
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]